# Inherited parent class values are not reflected in JPA save entity

Tags: java, spring

I have a class `Vehicle` and `Car`

**`Vehicle extends Car`**

Lets take an example

```
Class Vehicle {
  String vehicleMade;
  boolean fourWheeler;

  Vehicle(String vehicleMade, boolean fourWheeler) {
    this.vehicleMade=vehicleMade;
    this.fourWheeler=fourWheeler;
  }

  // getters and setters
}

Class Car extends Vehicle {
  String model;

  Car(String vehicleMade, boolean fourWheeler) {
    super(vehicleMade, fourWheeler);
  }

  // getters and setters
}

Class JavaMainClass {

  private static CarInfoRepository carInfoRepo;
  private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx;

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    carInfoRepo= ctx.getBean(CarInfoRepository.class);

    //Now where I have doubt and problem

    Car carInfo = new Car("Bentley", true);
    carinfo.setModel("Flying Spur");

    log.debug(carInfo.getVehicleMade); // I get Bentley here

    carInfoRepo.save(carInfo);
  }
}
```

Now when I get the car object from the repo, I get **`vehicleMade`** and **`fourWheeler`** attribute as `null`

You can see when I get that `vehicleMade` before saving but after saving to the repo I am getting null as the attribute.

Comment: How did you define CarInfoRepository?

Comment: by Extending with `IgniteRepository<int, Car>` which extends CrudRepository so the save method in actual is like key, value therefore for above example `carInfoRepo.save(idValue, carInfo);`
But I guess it's not to do anything with Repository?

Comment: I think the problem comes to the definition of the repo (ctx.getBean(CarInfoRepository.class), may be not. Your repo is CarInfoRepository extends IgniteRepository<Car,Int> (extends CrudRepository<T,Id>)?

Comment: @Ehcnalb it is resolved now

Comment: Great for you !